# Android project loading to phone removes previously installed project

Tags: android

I am working with Eclipse and running my apps on my phone(Motorola DROID2 GLOBAL, Android 2.2). Once I install a new project the previous one will disappear. Any ideas? Is this Eclipse problem or the phone?

Answer (score 1):

Is a normal behavior of the Android development enviroment, it remove the application that you're debugging to upload the new one (new version).
It is like when you update an application with the Market, the old one will dissapear.

Comment: I ment to say, not the previous version of the same application, but the previous project that I worked on.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to the operating system. Once I got upgrade pushed on my phone I stopped having this issue. Now it's all works just fine and  can see all my apps available.